# How to install a second graphics card and use 4 monitors?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I finally decided to take the plunge and ditch windows. After several hours I got things working perfectly with all my apps installed. Only problem is that I run 4 desktop displays off 2 nvidia adapters, the first adapter (GeForce GT 240) with two screens work perfectly but can't seem to get the second adapter (GeForce GT 620) installed. Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (AMD64)

Please help me with simple instructions please.
Terminal info to follow:

```
nachtland@nachtland-MS-7693:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT215 [GeForce GT 240] (rev a2)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 620] (rev a1)

nachtland@nachtland-MS-7693:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for nachtland: 

*-display            
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT215 [GeForce GT 240]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:82 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:fe000000-fe07ffff

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF108 [GeForce GT 620]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:83 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c8000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
nachtland@nachtland-MS-7693:~$
```

Comment: Exactly the same problem...

Comment: Ha, GOOD question but it is going to get difficult to answer without actually having 2 cards...  What I would do: remove all drivers for videocards. Shutdown. Remove 2nd card. Boot. Install driver. Copy xorg.conf over to safe place. Shutdown. Remove 1st card. Install 2nd card in other slot. Boot. Install driver. copy xorg.conf over to safe place. MERGE the 2 xorg.conf. Move it back. Shutdown system. Insert 2nd card. Boot and start praying.

Comment: Links that might help: https://cornerstone.multitouch.fi/cornerstone-documentation/multiple-graphics-cards http://superuser.com/questions/117239/how-can-i-get-multiple-video-cards-to-work-on-linux

Comment: The freaky thing is, before I decided on the Standard desktop version I tried the Mythbuntu flavour on a live usb and it supported the two screen adapters out of the box.

Comment: Hmm then Mythbuntu might have some changes we need in Ubuntu ;)

Comment: Other option: install Ubuntu on Mythbuntu? :D

Comment: `ARM 64` is a typo I guess?

Comment: Yeah sorry! (AMD 64) AMD FX8350

Comment: I don't have the cards/monitors to test but have you tried `arandr`? It looks like it could do the trick. It's a drag and drop front end for xrandr and appears to allow precise positioning. Let us know if it works for you! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult I am using four monitors on Linux Mint 64, this is my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Also using the recomended binary driver from Ubuntu0.0.4 nvidia-331 .113

```
Section "ServerLayout"

#    Screen   2  "Screen2"  LeftOf  "Screen0"
#    Screen   3  "Screen3"  LeftOf  "Screen2"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "on"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
    Option         "Clone" "off"
    # You would need one screen for each monitor
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics W2253"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Philips 190WV"
    HorizSync       0.0 - 0.0
    VertRefresh     0.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"

#    Driver      "nouveau"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 730"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 730"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
Option "AddARGBGLXVisuals" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

#    DefaultDepth    24
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#    EndSubSection
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

#    DefaultDepth    24
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#    EndSubSection
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-0: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0 {rotation=right}, VGA-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Maybe will help, because this was the hardest thing to get

Comment: lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0f02 (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0f02 (rev a1)